# Отклонение приложения из-за несовместимости с iPad

Tags: appstore, xcode, ios

Доброго времени суток.

У меня такая проблема с модерацией в App Store: мое приложение отклонили, потому что оно некорректно работает на iPad. Но приложение написано только для iPhone и не предназначено для запуска на планшете. Как это объяснить цензорам? Может, в iTunes Connect есть меню выбора, для какого устройства написано приложение? Надеюсь на Вашу скорейшую помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: А Вы в настройках проекта в XCode какую целевую платформу выбрали?

Comment: Только iPhone, я и сам думал, что из-за этого, но нет

Comment: Тогда могу предложить только обратиться в саппорт. Попробуйте добавить скриншот из настроек с указанием платформы. Они обновили сайт и у них могут возникнуть проблемы.
 Уже сталкивался с подобным - помогают оперативно.

Comment: Саппорт - это та штука, где два бесплатных запроса а потом платить надо?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/contact/
По вопросам оплаты не уточнял, но за время моей работы обращались туда неоднократно.

Comment: Смотрите, что нашел в правилах размещения в магазине:

>iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Не могу понять, как это? Мне цензоры кинули скриншот с планшета, там приложение обрезано снизу, т. к. на планшете запустилась версия для 4 дюймов. Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моя проблема решилась. Я написал в поддержку Apple, и там мне ответили, что если приложение не отмечено как iPhone only, то оно, хоть и написано для iPhone, автоматически будет запускаться и на iPad. Чтобы выбрать поддерживаемые устройства нужно зайти в Info.plist и внести изменения в Required device capatibilities. Нужно добавить строку, которая определит, какие устройства поддерживаются.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

Это ссылка на список возможных вариантов этой строки.